# Odd row/column dimensions in ScrollBar template

Tags: wpf

I was looking through default control template for ScrollBar and I've encountered this Grid definition for Vertical ScrollBar

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}" />
      <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
      <RowDefinition MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Same goes for Horizontal ScrollBar, with same value for width in ColumnDefinition.

What is the purpose of such definition of size of track area (0.00001*)? I've changed it to simple 1* and there is no difference in appearance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `RowDefinition.Height` is `1*`. So the other two rows are also sized relatively, since the template's only setting a `MaxHeight` and not overriding `Height`'s default value.

The code excerpt in the OP should be exactly the same as this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="1*"
                     MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}" />
      <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="1*" 
                     MaxHeight="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarButtonHeightKey}}" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Meaning that the central row has near-zero height in comparison with the other two, unless those two get to their MaxHeight. In that case, the central row is "allowed" to increase in size and occupy all the space left.

If it seems like setting `1*` is working for you, it's probably because you haven't tried an scenario where both scroll buttons are very close to each other.

With `0.00001*`, the buttons shouldn't shrink until they're touching each other. For instance:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
             TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This code produces the default behavior:

[image: default behavior of the scroll buttons when stretched][image: default behavior of the scroll buttons when shrunk]

With `1*`, the buttons should begin to shrink before they touch, and won't actually touch each other at all, leaving a proportional free space between them all the time.

This code...

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
             TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="18" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Produces this:

[image: behavior of the scroll buttons when stretched with height set to one star][image: behavior of the scroll buttons when shrunk with height set to one star]

Answer (score 0):

This will not make any difference if there is only row with somevalue* height. You will start noticing difference when there are more rows with different somevalue* heights.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect it should be so. Other rows definitely have absolute pixel size (because ScrollBar button dimension is defined by system metrics), but Microsoft is steadily using 0.00001 in templates in all themes (Luna, Aero, Aero2), different companies do this as well (e.g. ComponentOne). I don't think it is just a coincidence, some trick with layout rounding perhaps

Comment: By default, RowDefinition.Height is 1*. So THERE ARE other rows with a "star" value in those definitions, since the template's only setting a MaxHeight and not overriding Height's default value.